# Open Winform in expanded screen only

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've developed an application in fullscreen mode, i.e:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class FormMain
Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    Me.Size = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize
    Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultLocation
End Sub
```

The line that opens the form without the menu bar is `Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None` , which makes me unable to drag and drop the application in the expanded screen.

I'm starting the application in my computer in the office, but the purpose is to show in the screen outside my room.

Thank you

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `is there a programming way to open it in the other screen by default` ? :)

Comment: The `Screen` class will probably help you on your way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Me.Location = Screen.AllScreens(1).WorkingArea.Location
Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

I would also suggest checking `AllScreens` contains more than 1 element before setting it to that in case this app is ever run on a system that only has 1 screen.

Comment: nope, still same result. I also dragged the .exe file to the screen that i want it to be, and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: oh wait. it works this way! I have to change line 4 to line 1 and it runs properly. Ty, it wasn't easy :)